# Optimal (compromise) Path in a Graph based on two metrics (distance, cost)

Tags: algorithm, graph, routes

As you can see from my stats, I am pretty new in this forum, although I have been using stackoverflow.com for several years as a source of answers to my programming questions. I pray that you overlook any minor faux pas i may be committing and share your thoughts to my little issue below.

I am wondering if there is a routing/path-finding algorithm that is able find the optimum path over time and cost of possible routes. Ideally I could specify preference for time, cost, or best time at best cost.

I have been using the Dijksta Algorithm for routing a shortest Path on a directed and weighted rectangular network. All nodes are connected via directional edges to their left, right, up and down as well as their 45° neighbors. That means all nodes have 8 edges, minus the non-existing edges at the outside borders. All nodes are reachable, but the metric (distance) can be increased to reflect a higher cost. I can run the route finder with a different edge list on the same nodes, representing the cost (or distance) aspect when traversing them and so find the lowest Cost, or the fasted route. It gave me the shortest routes with the metrics of distance (1 or SQRT(2) for corner Edges).

Now I had been wondering about a way to mash up the distance and the cost aspect by simply multiplying them and so generating a mixed metric. What do you think about this approach, or is the a way to make a routing algorithm selecting a different "optimum" neighbor to find the best route either time, cost or compromise.

Thanks.

Comment: You're asking (I think) for a function of time and cost to weight edges. What properties should this function have? Without some constraints, it's impossible to answer without guessing what you actually want. All you say is you want a "mash up" and a "mixed metric", but there's a continuum of functions that satisfy this.

Comment: In short, yes, you can just multiply the distance and time each by different constants and add them.  Dijkstra will still "work", and this is a sensible and also efficient way to trade off these quantities against each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any known algorithms(Dijkstra, Floyd–Warshall) in new algebra.
Think about your distance as a struct with two fields:

```
struct Distance {
    int cost, distance;
}
```

now you need to define operator< and operator+. 
If you want best time at best cost, you should use:

```
bool operator<(Distance d1, Distance d2) {   
   if (d1.cost == d2.cost) 
       return d1.time1 < d2.time
   else 
       return d1.cost < d2.cost; 
}
```

or some weighting:

```
bool operator<(Distance d1, Distance d2) {   
   return wCost*d1.cost + wDistance*d1.distance < wCost*d2.cost + wDistance*d2.distance
}
```

Comment: Thank you taarraas! 
That is a very sensible approach. I like the option 1 because i goes along the notion I had as well, but with option 2 I could bring in even more parameters, like speed, etc.